# Placholder for tags

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

Is it possible to set a placeholder for Select2 tags control?

```
$(containerID).select2({
    multiple: true,
    tags: allTags,
    placeholderOption: "Tags"
});
```

`placeholderOption` for select works fine but for tags there is no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need anything but the `placeholder` attribute in your input, like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="select2-input" 
    placeholder="Tags placeholder" style="width:300px" />

<script>
    $("#select2-input").select2({
        tags: [],
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

An Alternate way of doing so inside the select2() rather than using an inline HTML attribute

```
$(containerID).select2({
    placeholder: "No tags yet, type here to tag",
    tags: [],
});
```